# npm: в каких случаях следует использовать @scope?

Tags: node.js, npm

Я не читал документацию к npm полностью, но среди примеров, которые я видел, @scope использовался только для обозначения пользователя или организации:

```
@username/project-name
@orgname/project-name
```

Хорошо, а какие @scope ещё можно использовать?
Допустим, мы пишем библиотеки, расширяющие фреймворк bootstrap; следует ли все ли библиотеки объединить в scope с именем @bootstrap, или в данном случае следует использовать исключительно префиксирование типа `boostrap-libname`?

### Обновление вопроса в связи с конкурсом

Что если имя npm-организации и имя проекта не совпадает? Например, организация @foo разработала библиотеки @bar и @baz. И какой тогда скоуп надо указывать для библиотек bar и baz?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы автор большой либы. У вас есть проект на гитхабе с отдельным именем. Вы разделяете один пакет на более мелкие модули. Вы регаете на npm организацию. Теперь название этой организации и есть ваш скоп. Только члены этой организации могут туда заливать пакеты.

Вот так это работает. Очевидные плюсы - никаких name сквоттеров. Внутри вашей орги никто не уведёт красивое имя. Минусы - старые npm клиенты не поддерживают скопы.

Вот пример организации https://www.npmjs.com/org/babel

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Я понял, что в случае с организациями имеет смысл создавать @scope с именем организации. А вот например, в случае с семейством библиотек babel, у разработчиков был смысл создавать scope с именем @babel?

Comment: @БоковГлеб само сабой. babel это уже довольно успешный и известный продукт с тонной плагинов. Как минимум, добавление плагина в организацию говорит о его официальной поддержке.

Comment: @БоковГлеб `laravel-automation-deploy2vps` и `@laravel/automation-deploy2vps` с точки зрения npm это 2 разных пакета. Вы не сможете создать второй пакет не будучи членом организации `laravel` в npm.

Comment: зря я привёл в пример laravel, потому что это существующая организация в npm и тут всё однозначно (как Вы и сказали). Заменил скоуп на несуществующий ralaver, который не обязан быть организацией.