# Какой npm-scope следует выбрать, если у одной организации несколько проектов?

Tags: node.js, npm

К сожалению, так и не получил исчерпывающего ответа на вопрос [npm: в каких случаях следует использовать @scope?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876336/npm-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-scope), но по крайней мере, родился более конкретный вопрос "в лоб".

Предположим, что некоторая зарегистрированная на npm-организация `@foo` разрабатывает библиотеки `@bar` и `@hoge`, аналогичных `@babel` и `@vue`, причём у каждой из них уйма дочерних библиотек: `@bar/core`,  `@bar/register`, `@hoge/validation`, `@hoge/animation` и другие.

Какой scope организации следует выбрать для каждой из этих библиотек - scope организации `@foo` или скоупы проектов `@bar` и `@hoge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выберите скоп организации. Организации как раз и были придуманы для того, чтобы объединять внутри себя библиотеки.

Нет в npm понятия `дочерняя библиотека`. Внутри одной библиотеки может находиться несколько js файлов, например `index.js` (который объявлен main), тогда подключении либы `bar` из организации `foo` будет `@foo/bar`. Однако если вы хотите в либу добавить дополнительную отдельную функциональность, и положите её в файл `register.js`, то файл будет подключаться как `@foo/bar/register`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!