# Что значит "организация" в контексте npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Из ответа на вопрос

[Какой npm-scope следует выбрать, если у одной организации несколько проектов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898652/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-npm-scope-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

я узнал, что `npm-@scope` создаётся один на каждую организацию, даже если одна организация выпускает несколько совершенно разных библиотек. С тем случаем, когда какой-то скоуп соответствует конкретной реально существующей компании, всё понятно.

Не совсем понятны такие скоупы, как `@types` - серия библиотек с определениями TypeScript-типов. Совершенно ясно, что `@types`- это не корпорация, которая создала свой аккаунт на npm. А что, если владелец скоупа `@types` надумает какой-то другой проект на npm опубликовать, совершенно не имеющий отношения к TypeScript?

Регистрировать новую npm-организацию, оплатить аккаунт и создать новый скоуп?

Выше я употреблял слово "организация" без понимания того, что оно значит в контексте npm, и цель данного вопроса - разобраться в этом.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/orgs/

Comment: @AlexeyTen, эта ссылка подошла бы как ответ на вопрос для англоязычного StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надеюсь эта информация поможет чуть лучше понять что за такие возможности сейчас есть у NPM.

scope создается для каждого пользователя или организации. [Ссылка](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) на документацию NPM. Это позволяет создавать всем пакеты с одним именем, просто у них будет разный scope. Добавлять в scope созданный для обычного пользователя может только один человек.

Org это механизм создания одноименного scope, доступ к которому имеет больше чем один человек. [Ссылка](https://docs.npmjs.com/orgs/) на документацию NPM. И для создания приватных пакетов еще и платить надо за каждого участника.

@types это scope принадлежащий Microsoft. Вот [ссылка](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/the-future-of-declaration-files-2/) на запись в официальном блоге. И думаю правильно предполагать что они могут там выкладывать то что им заблагорассудится.

@babel похоже scope ныне используемый проектом Babel, для организации пакетной архитектуры проекта. [Ссылка](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration) на упоминание в руководстве по миграции на 7 версию.

Если я правильно понимаю, то под словом Org подразумевают не столько компанию, сколько некоторый упорядоченный набор людей с правами доступа к пакетам в соответствующем scope.

Comment: Замечательный ответ! Мне остаётся только принять Ваш ответ, проголосовать за него и наградить Вас репутацией.

Comment: @БоковГлеб согласен, отличный ответ. А что не приняли?

Comment: Приношу свои извинения. Сейчас исправлю.